# Llenar formArray con JSON en Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Quiero editar un registro que tiene varios arreglos, pero no logro hacer que funcione.

Recibo un JSON donde tengo todo los datos que almacene y quiero editar

```
project: {
    "id": 1,
    "customer": "Jhonathan",
    "steps": "{\"id\":1,\"paso\":\"Paso 1\",\"accion\":\"accion 1\",\"punto_critico\":\"punto critico 1\",\"razon\":\"razon 1\",\"fichero\":\"fileImage",\"namefile\":\"3.jpg\"}",
    "epp": "{\"zapatos\":\"zapatos\",\"guantes\":\"guantes\",\"mandil\":\"mandil\",\"lentes\":\"lentes\",\"faja\":\"faja\",\"chaleco\":\"chaleco\",\"tapones\":\"tapones\",\"mascarilla\":\"mascarilla\",\"otro\":\"\"}",
    "turns": "[\"2 Turno\"]",
    "created_at": "2021-01-13T15:20:49.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-01-15T02:20:33.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null
}
```

En mi formulario lo tengo como un formGroup y despues le coloco los formArray

```
editProject = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [1],
  customer: [''],
  steps: this.formBuilder.array([this.newStep]),
  epp: new FormGroup({
    zapatos: new FormControl(''),
    guantes: new FormControl(''),
    mandil: new FormControl(''),
    lentes: new FormControl(''),
    faja: new FormControl(''),
    chaleco: new FormControl(''),
    tapones: new FormControl(''),
    mascarilla: new FormControl(''),
    otro: new FormControl(''),
  }),
  turns: [[]],
})
```

Y esta es la manera en como creo los pasos (steps)

```
getNewId() {
    this.currentStepId += 1;
    return this.currentStepId;
  }

  get newStep(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [this.getNewId()],
      paso: ['Paso ' + this.currentStepId],
      accion: [''],
      punto_critico: [''],
      razon: [''],
      fichero: ['']
    })
  }

  get steps(): FormArray {
    return this.editProject.get('steps') as FormArray
  }

  Addsteps() {
    this.steps.push(this.newStep);
  }
```

Este es mi HTML

```
<mat-card class="example-card text-center col-md-offset-1" style="width: 85%;">
    <div class="col s12 m11 l9">
        <p style="color:red"><strong><i>Algunos campos pueden mostrarse vacíos. No se alarme, podrá dejarlos vacíos y no se perderá la información.</i></strong></p>
        <div class="example-action-buttons">
            <button mat-button (click)="accordion.openAll()">
                Expandir todo
            </button>
            <button mat-button (click)="accordion.closeAll()">
                Contraer todo
            </button>
        </div>
        <form [formGroup]="editProject" autocomplete="off" (submit)="onSubmit()">
            <mat-accordion class="example-headers-align" multi>
                <!-- ABRIR PROYECTO -->
                <mat-expansion-panel class="mb-1">
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header class="disable_ripple">
                        <mat-panel-title class="header-text">
                            Abrir proyecto
                        </mat-panel-title>
                        <mat-panel-description class="header-text">
                            Comience a editar su proyecto
                            <mat-icon>work</mat-icon>
                        </mat-panel-description>
                    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <div class="row mt-4">
                        <!-- APARTADO DE NOMBRE DE CLIENTE Y CREACION DE NUEVO -->
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <mat-form-field class="col-md-12">
                                <mat-label>Cliente</mat-label>
                                <input matInput type="text" formControlName="customer"/>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <a disabled mat-button color="agregar" class="btn-panel btn-block">
                                <mat-icon>add</mat-icon> Agregar cliente
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </mat-expansion-panel>

                <!-- PASOS A SEGUIR -->
                <mat-expansion-panel class="mb-1">
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header class="disable_ripple">
                        <mat-panel-title class="header-text">
                            Pasos a seguir
                        </mat-panel-title>
                        <mat-panel-description class="header-text">
                            Indique aquí los pasos para su correcta verificación
                            <i class="material-icons">format_list_numbered</i>
                        </mat-panel-description>
                    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="mt-4">
                        <p style="color:red"><strong><i>En caso de querer actualizar los pasos, favor de agregar los nuevos. <br> De lo contrario puede omitir esta sección</i></strong></p>
                        <fieldset formArrayName="steps" class="col-12">
                            <fieldset class="container mb-4 p-3" name="steps"
                                *ngFor="let step of steps.controls; let i = index"
                                style="vertical-align: middle" [formGroupName]="i">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <h4>Paso {{ i + 1 }}</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <mat-form-field class="col-12">
                                            <mat-label>Paso</mat-label>
                                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="paso" />
                                        </mat-form-field>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <mat-form-field class="col-12">
                                            <mat-label>Acción</mat-label>
                                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="accion" />
                                        </mat-form-field>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <mat-form-field class="col-12">
                                            <mat-label>Punto critico</mat-label>
                                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="punto_critico" />
                                        </mat-form-field>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <mat-form-field class="col-12">
                                            <mat-label>Razón</mat-label>
                                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="razon" />
                                        </mat-form-field>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <mat-form-field class="col-md-12">
                                            <a mat-button class="btn-panel btn-block" color="agregar">
                                                <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                                                <mat-label>Añadir evidencia</mat-label>
                                                <ngx-mat-file-input formControlName="fichero"
                                                    placeholder="Basic Input" (change)="onChangeFile($event, i)"
                                                    [accept]="'.png, .jpeg, .jpg, .gif'">
                                                </ngx-mat-file-input>
                                            </a>
                                        </mat-form-field>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <img [src]="step.value.fichero" width="150px" class="mb-4" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <a mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="removeStep(i)">Remover
                                            paso</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </fieldset>
                        <a mat-raised-button color="paso" (click)="Addsteps()">Agregar paso</a>
                    </div>
                </mat-expansion-panel>

                <!-- EPP -->
                <mat-expansion-panel class="mb-1">
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header class="disable_ripple">
                        <mat-panel-title class="header-text"> EPP </mat-panel-title>
                        <mat-panel-description class="header-text">
                            Indique el equipo de protección personal necesario
                            <i class="material-icons">local_hospital</i>
                        </mat-panel-description>
                    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <hr />
                    <p style="color:red"><strong><i>En caso de querer actualizar el EPP, favor de agregar los nuevos. <br> De lo contrario puede omitir esta sección</i></strong></p>
                    <fieldset formGroupName="epp">
                        <div class="row mt-4">
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <mat-form-field class="col-12">
                                    <mat-label>Tipo de zapatos de seguridad</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="zapatos" />
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <mat-form-field class="col-12">
                                    <mat-label>Tipo de guantes</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="guantes" />
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <mat-form-field class="col-12">
                                    <mat-label>Tipo de Mandil</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="mandil" />
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <mat-form-field class="col-12">
                                    <mat-label>Tipo de lentes de seguridad</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="lentes" />
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <mat-form-field class="col-12">
                                    <mat-label>Tipo de faja</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="faja" />
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <mat-form-field class="col-12">
                                    <mat-label>Color de chaleco</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="chaleco" />
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <mat-form-field class="col-12">
                                    <mat-label>Tapones auditivos</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="tapones" />
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <mat-form-field class="col-12">
                                    <mat-label>Tipo de mascarilla</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="mascarilla" />
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <mat-form-field class="col-12">
                                    <mat-label>Otro</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="otro" />
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </mat-expansion-panel>

                <!-- ASIGNACION DE PERSONAL -->
                <mat-expansion-panel class="mb-1">
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header class="disable_ripple">
                        <mat-panel-title class="header-text">
                            Asignación de personal
                        </mat-panel-title>
                        <mat-panel-description class="header-text">
                            Asigne a su personal
                            <i class="material-icons">group</i>
                        </mat-panel-description>
                    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="row mt-4">
                        <div class="center-align col s12 mt-4" *ngFor="let item of turnsList">
                            <div class="input-field col s12 m4">
                                <mat-checkbox class="turno-check" color="primary"
                                    (change)="onChange(item.name, $event['checked'])" name="turn">
                                    {{ item.name }}
                                </mat-checkbox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </mat-expansion-panel>
                <div class="spinner-container spin-submit" *ngIf="loading">
                    <mat-spinner diameter="24"></mat-spinner>
                    <p>Procesando información...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="spinner-container" *ngIf="!loading">
                    <button class="btn disable_ripple btn-block btn-md" [disabled]="!editProject.valid">
                        ENVIAR/SOLICITAR AUTORITZACION DE EDICION DE PROYECTO
                    </button>
                </div>
            </mat-accordion>
        </form>
    </div>
</mat-card>
```

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar a saber como puedo hacer el llenado, lo intente con patchValue pero no lo consegui

> Actualizado

Hoy intente colocar los valores de la siguiente manera

```
response.project.steps.forEach( valor => this.steps.push(valor))
```

pero me muestra un error en consola

```
*ERROR TypeError: response.project.steps.forEach is not a function*
```

Comment: Faltaría la parte HTML, si la puedes añadir, para ver cómo estás declarando el formulario en el HTML. Además de eso, ¿te da algún error la consola?

Comment: @Sema Acabo de agregar el HTML, y lo que le agrege hoy

Comment: @[cesg.dev] Pero ese código no está completo aún, cierto? En el error que indicas, hace referencia a un `response`(que será la respuesta de back, el JSON), pero podrías completar dónde aparece esa lógica en tu código? Si no, también puedes tratar de montar un ejemplo en [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-o5uogh) que puedes añadir dependencia a material.